# how to use two scrollable gallery in 2 column Images and text From url using webservice?

Tags: android, scroll, android-gallery

you can see in the image i have  two columns both have images scrolled in scrlling so is gallery or something else also if user scroll any of the column automatically scroll 2 column how it possible give me any hint for this layot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use vertical viewpager. https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager and each view of the adapter must contains the two picks. Example:

```
public class PicsAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    View item1, item2;

    .....
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position){

        View v = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.account_list_item, null);

        item1 = v.findViewById(R.id.item1);
        item1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){....}


        if( position*2+1 < pics.size()){

            item2 = v.findViewById(R.id.item2);
            item2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        .... 
                    }

            });


        }else{
            //hide 
            v.findViewById(R.id.item2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } 


        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }
}
```